# How to find probability from a fitted copula in R?

Tags: r, graph, 3d, probability-theory

I need to find probability using a fitted copula. For example, the Student t copula was used. Then the random bivariate variable `tsim01` was generated with the `rCopula()` function on range [0,1].

As I understand I should compute the value of bivariate copula function `tcopula` at corresponded points `0< p1, p2<1`.

I have tried to use the function `prob()` from the package `copula`. I setup the values of `p1=0.4`, `p2=0.7` and a some small `delta=1e-3`. Thus I have definded the small hypercube. The probability is 0.1036955.
My example is below.

```
library(copula)

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
N <- 100
set.seed(1)
df = cbind(as.data.frame(rnorm(N)), 
           as.data.frame(rnorm(N))); 

mymargins      = c("norm", "norm")
myparamMargins = list(list(mean=mean(df[,1]), sd=sd(df[,1])), 
                      list(mean=mean(df[,2]), sd=sd(df[,2])))

# Student t copula

tcopula  <- tCopula(dim=2, dispstr="un", df=2, df.fixed=TRUE) 
tfit     <- fitCopula(tcopula, pobs(as.matrix(df)), method='ml')
trho     <- coef(tfit); 

tcopula <- mvdc(copula=tCopula(trho, dim=2, df=3), 
                    margins=mymargins, 
                    paramMargins=myparamMargins)             

tsim01   <- rCopula(N, tCopula(trho, dim=2, df=3))

p1 <- 0.4; p2 <- 0.7; delta <- 1e-3

prob(tCopula(trho, dim=2, df=3), c(p1, p1+delta), c(p2, p2+delta))
# [1] 0.1036955
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  persp(tcopula, dMvdc, main="pdf", xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2), 
        xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="c(x,y)")
  contour(tcopula, dMvdc, main="Contour pdf", xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2),
          xlab="x", ylab="y")
  plot(tsim01, main="tCopula, Simulated values on [0,1]^2", 
       xlab="z1", ylab="z2", pch=16, col="blue")
       abline(h=p2,v=p1)
```

Am I correctly applying the function `prob()`? How to check the answer with a 3D pdf plot or a contour plot?

**Edit.** Possible alternative way is to use [a conditional CDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124865/sampling-from-conditional-copula?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

**Edit 2.** Possible alternative way 2 is to use the quantile transformation C(p1, p2)=t_df_trho(t_df_trho^-1(p1), t_df_trho^-1(p2)).

```
p1_new <- qt(p1, df=3) # t_df_trho^-1(p1) is the inverce of t_df_trho()
p2_new <- qt(p2, df=3) # t_df_trho^-1(p2)
```

But I don't know what a function `t_df_trho` should I use? The function `t_df_trho` is  the bivariate Student-t distribution function, `df` is the number of degree freedom, and `trho` is the correlation coefficient.